# magento2 I want to add a block shows the current exchange rate between the euro and US dollar on everypage

Tags: magento2

widget or ohthers I shoule use?when I read some course,widget like static block,how to get a real time exchange rate in block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a custom module
create a file in app/code/My/Module/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
            <block class="My\Module\Block\ExchangeRate" name="mymodule.exchangerate"  template="My_Module::exchange_rate.phtml" after="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now create the template file where u out html structure and the data
app/code/My/Module/view/frontend/templates/exchange_rate.phtml

```
<?php
/**
    @var $this \My\Module\Block\ExchangeRate
*/
$rate =   $this->getRate();
?>
<div class="mymodule-exchange-rate>
    <div>The exchange rate between euros and dollar are <?= $rate; ?></div>
</div>
```

Final step for pass data to the phtml create a file
app/code/My/Module/Block/ExchangeRate.php

```
<?php
namespace My\Module\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class ExchangeRate extends Template
{

    public function __construct(Template\Context $context, array $data = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getRate()
    {
        $MyRate = "";//Do stuff for get the exchange rate
        return $MyRate
    }

}
```

Comment: it is work,is,that defult.xml is the layout file for everypage?

Comment: yes magento will take de default.xml for build every page of frontend